# What will happen if tasks take long time in onStop()

Tags: android

Consider I want to save some data in database in onStop() method of my app and I use AsyncTask to execute queries , or doing any kind of tasks that take long time to perform , so what will happen ? Does activity wait to complete task ? my tasks will be done correctly ?

p.s: I want to do this (saving data in onStop() ) because I dont want to execute query each time user click on a button and change something , I want to do it at the end . 
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask started in onStop will run to completion.  There shouldn't be any problems with that.  If it takes a really long time it may be restarted before it finishes, which could cause issues in your program depending on how you coded.

If the onStop function itself takes too long, you could trip a watchdog timer and your app may be killed.

Comment: So it means AsyncTask does its operations in background while Activity is gone ?

Comment: Yes.  An AsyncTask runs on a Thread.  Threads are not stopped when activities are stopped, or even when activities are destroyed.  The reason why is that there is no safe way to stop a Thread from an outside Thread in a generic way, unless you know what the Thread is doing and when its safe to terminate.  If you want that behavior you actually need to work to get it.

Answer (score 0):

First asynctasks are guaranteed to run to completion. but you should note that they can work tightly in synch with UI and you can modify some ui elements in the call backs of asynchTask (onProgressSubmit(), onComplete()...) but if you UI thread is not available on the event of these callbacks you may get an exception.

Second in some rare situations (low memory) in old APIs prior to API11 on stop method may not get called so it is better to save you data in another call back such as (on pause).

Comment: but as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html we should not perform tasks like saving data in onPause

Comment: We don't run the actual task in the on pause, we trigger an asynch task to do the job, I said on pause because it is guaranteed to run on older apis